# RoR: how can I paginate all of my users microposts all in one place?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I want the home page to show everyones microposts, but I keep getting errors. I feel like this might be because the microposts have a belong_to has_many relationship with users. But anyways, This is the code for the home page..

```
      <section>
        <%= render 'shared/user_info' %>
      </section>

      <section>
        <div id= "purchases">
          <%= render 'shared/micropost_form_purchase' %>
        </div>
        <div id="sales">
          <%= render 'shared/micropost_form_sale' %>
        </div>
      </section>



<ol class="microposts">
  <%= render @microposts %>
</ol>
<%= will_paginate @microposts %>
```

and it gives me this error: 'nil' is not an ActiveModel-compatible object that returns a valid partial path. at the bottom.

I added

```
 def home

    @microposts = Micropost.all


  end
```

to the microposts controller.

can anyone help me out? please?

Answer (score 0):

The call to render is looking for a partial view that it can't find.  If you're keeping all your partials in views/shared/, then do you have a views/shared/micropost.html.erb for it to render?

Comment: yes I do, but the error is at the last four lines where I am trying to paginate the microposts.